# Framework for parsing the input configuration of network devices

Tags: ios, parsing, cisco

Frameworks like Genie Parser or TextFSM parse the *output* of the configuration. That is what the device answers when you ask it about some part of the configuration, like `show ip route` or `show access-lists`.

For example, this is the output of ACLs and it can be parsed by the aforementioned frameworks:

```
switch1#show access-lists
Standard IP access list acl-snmp-4
    10 permit 10.0.0.1
    20 permit 10.0.0.2
    30 permit 192.168.0.1
    40 permit 192.168.0.2
```

What I'm looking for is parsing the *input* - the text people need to type in when configuring the device. This is useful when one wants to programatically verify that the configuration standard is correct.

For example, verify that the following snippet has the correct IPs:

```
ip access-list standard ACL1

remark Server1
permit host 10.0.0.1
permit host 10.0.0.2
remark Server2
permit host 192.0.0.3
permit 54.101.80.0 0.0.0.63
```

I'm using some *for* loops and regex at the moment, but it gets messy when you get dozens of device types, OS types, config styles.

Answer (score 0):

With `show access-list` you can see the operational data and not directly the configuration and yes, Genie or TextFSM are solutions to convert operational text output into structured data.

For configuration data, I would recommend to take a look at [ttp](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

I'm not quite sure what use case you are trying to solve. If you want to generate configuration, why not use a templating engine? For example, [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/)

The CLI is not really designed for automation, so check if your devices have proper APIs like netconf-yang.